# I am trying to code flappy bird but the pipes wont spawn correctly

Tags: lua, love2d

I am creating a flappy bird clone The pipes just seem to spawn randomly without any `math.random()`
I don't know what is happening I used If statement to spawn the pipes and not a for loop
The pipes seem to be a bit cursed in this case

````
        pipe1 = Pipe(WINDOW_WIDTH-54, 0,54,topSpace)
        pipe2 = Pipe(WINDOW_HEIGHT-54, topSpace+bottomSpace, 54, WINDOW_WIDTH-bottomSpace-60-15)
    end
        Pipes()
    function SecondPipes()
        pipe3 = Pipe(490, 0,54,topSpace)
        pipe4 = Pipe(490, topSpace+bottomSpace, 54, WINDOW_WIDTH-bottomSpace-60-15)

    end
    SecondPipes()
    end

    function love.update(dt)

        if pipe1.x + pipe1.width and pipe2.x + pipe2.width < 0 then
            pipe1.x  = WINDOW_WIDTH
            pipe2.x  = WINDOW_WIDTH

        end
        if pipe3.x + pipe3.width and pipe3.x + pipe3.width < 0 then
            pipe3.x  = WINDOW_WIDTH
            pipe3.x  = WINDOW_WIDTH

        end

    pipe1:update(dt)
    pipe2:update(dt)
    pipe3:update(dt)
    pipe4:update(dt)


end```
````

Comment: First of all, format that code. Then fix the obvious errors, like the expressions `pipe1.x + pipe1.width`  which are always true since a number evaluates to true. I assume you are missing a `< 0` here. Then add the rest of the relevant code, e.g. drawing and updating pipes. And maybe further explain what random means. Where are the pipes, and where did you expect them to be.